# Error: g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I don't have a very good understanding of how makefiles function in c++, but I had been using this one for the entirety of this project without issue. Suddenly, it seems, I'm receiving the above error when trying to make the program.

Below is my makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAG=-g -c

PA2 : main.o
    $(CC) -o PA2 main.o -lm

main.o: utility.h Binary_node.h Binary_tree.h Search_tree.h AVL_node.h AVL_tree.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
```

Any help fixing and/or understanding this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: `CFLAG` should be `CFLAGS`. Maybe you accidentally deleted the `S`

Comment: What happens if you change the main.o: line to `main.o: main.cpp utility.h Binary_node.h Binary_tree.h Search_tree.h AVL_node.h AVL_tree.h`

Comment: It would be more normal practice to have `-c` in the build command, not in CFLAGS